# How do i make a path on a canvas (HTML5) move a a certain angle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a path that is a triangle and i am trying to move it forward a certain length at a specific angle,

```
this.x += length*Math.sin(this.angle); 
this.y -= -length*Math.cos(this.angle);
```

length is the amount of distance forward and angle is the angle at which the path is facing. When i run it, and the angle is 90 degrees it moves on the `x` correctly but changes the `y`.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the unit-circle and it's concepts? 0 degrees points right (increasing X), 90 degrees points up. (increasing Y). cos(0) = 1, sin(0) = 0 - have a closer look at which function you've used for which axis. Also remember that 'up' on a computer screen is decreasing Y, rather than increasing, as it is in the 'rea' world.

Comment: No, I haven't taken trig yet I'm in 7th grade

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out!** I was not converting the angle value to a radian, witch is what the sin and cos functions take, here is my new code

```
this.x+=length*Math.sin(parseInt(this.angle)*Math.PI/180);
this.y-=length*Math.cos(parseInt(this.angle)*Math.PI/180);
```